# Flexbox: column and column-reverse directions break image aspect ratios

Tags: css, flexbox

Given a very simple layout:

```css
div{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

img{
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

section{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <section>hello world</section>
    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/26903">
</div>
```

the image will not honor its aspect ratio (which it would normally do with an `auto` height and constrained `max-width`) and will instead always display at its actual height.

I'm trying to figure out why this is the case: is there something special about `flex-direction: column` and `flex-direction: column-reverse` that cause this to happen?

My current theory is that it's because the `column` and `column-reverse` directions want the main constraining property of the image to be `height` or `max-height` (since we now have a stack of things flowing and constrained vertically instead of horizontally), and that the parent `div` would need a fixed height to make the whole thing work. Playing around with the Fiddle below seems to indicate that may be the case, but can anyone confirm?

[Here's a fiddle with the same markup and styling.](https://jsfiddle.net/_ajm/eyzx5a9s/1/)

Comment: Which browser do you use? I can't reproduce.

Comment: I ran this against Chrome 48.